# Reaction most dominant product for a low concentration nucleophile

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

If i got this reaction, and I determine that it will react in a Sn1 mechanism, will the dominant product will be in the results of the EtOH/H2O or CN-?

[image]

I think, the main product will be with the CN- after the hydrid shift in the Sn1 mechanism, and we will get a non chiral product, but im really not sure cause it says low concentration of the CN- nucleophile.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I think, the main product will be with the CN- after the hydrid shift in the Sn1 mechanism, and we will get a non chiral product, but im really not sure cause it says low concentration of the CN- nucleophile

Comment: Edit your question to include your thoughts. The question is poorly phased in that it does not indicate whether an equivalent of CN- is present even if it is in low concentration. Secondary alkyl halides undergo substitution by a mix of SN1 and SN2 and the conditions are set up to favour SN1

Comment: As SN1, this is definitely a solvolysis.